# How to keep selected value in dropdown after click button

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to keep the selected value visible after the users click the connect button. How do I keep the selected value in this dropdown still appear when the user has clicked the connect button? This is the preview of my application:

[image: Before clicked]

[image: After clicked]

And this is my code:

```dart
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('servers')
          .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text('Something went wrong');
    }
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Text("Loading");
    }
    return Container(
      child: DropdownSearch<String>(
        dropdownDecoratorProps: DropDownDecoratorProps(
          dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Server",
            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFB4F4C8)),
            hintText: "Select a server",
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFB4F4C8)),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.map_outlined,
              color: Color(0xFFB4F4C8),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFB4F4C8)),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFB4F4C8)),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
          ),
        ),
        dropdownBuilder: ((context, selectedItem) {
          Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_circle_outlined,
            color: Color(0xFFB4F4C8),
          );
          return Text(selectedItem ?? "",
            style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFfcfcfc)),
          );
        }),
        items: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return data["address"];
        })
        .toList()
        .cast<String>(),
        onChanged: (var data) {
          dataAddress = data;
        }
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I have posted answer below is that helpful?

Comment: I check that your answer is nothing different with my code

Comment: but have you tried without `dropdownDecoratorProps: DropDownDecoratorProps` ?, as that worked for me while testing your code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not using `showSearchBox: true` on `DropdownSearch` widget.
Although [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search#customize-showed-field-itemasstring) shows that we can use `dropdownDecoratorProps: DropDownDecoratorProps` but in your case it seems it is not needed as there aren't many dropdown search fields.
Hence I have used it without those Props in my below code.

I have tried below code at my end i am able to list drop down. Here is the screenshot of my app :[image: my app]

**main.dart** with DropDownWidget :

```
class DropDownWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropDownWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<DropDownWidget> createState() => _DropDownWidgetState();
}

class _DropDownWidgetState extends State<DropDownWidget> {
  String? dataAddress;
final snappy = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('AppBar Demo')),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: snappy,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Something went wrong');
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Text("Loading");
          }
          return DropdownSearch<String>(
              dropdownSearchDecoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Server",
                hintText: "Select a server",
              ),
              dropdownBuilder: ((context, selectedItem) {
                const Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_drop_down_circle_outlined,
                );
                return Text(selectedItem ?? "");
              }),
              items: snapshot.data!.docs
                  .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    Map<String, dynamic> data =
                        document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                    return data["address"];
                  })
                  .toList()
                  .cast<String>(),
              onChanged: (var data) {
                dataAddress = data;
              });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```